# Prove weak convergence unique limit in normed vector space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space. Suppose that fro each $f \in X$ there is bounded linear functional $T \in X^*$ for which $T(f) =||f||$ and $||T||_* =1$

i Prove that if $\{f_n\}$ converges weakly in $X$ to both $f_1$ and $f_2$ then $f_1=f_2$

ii Prove that if $\{f_n\} \rightharpoonup f$ in $X$ then $||f|| 
\leq \liminf ||f_n||$

**Proof i**

Assume $f_n$ converge weakly in $X$ to both $f_1$ and $f_2$

$f_n \rightharpoonup f_1 \text{ (using definition of weak convergence) }\Leftrightarrow T(f_n) \to T(f)$ for all $T \in X^*$ where $X^*$ is dual space of $X$

Based problem given $T(f)=||f||$ we have $||f_n|| \to ||f_1||$

Using similar approach for $f_2$ we have $||f_n|| \to ||f_2|$

Now consider $||f_1 -f_2||$

\begin{align*}
||f_1 -f_2|| = &||f_n - f_n + f_1-f_2||\\
&=||(f_n -f_2) + (f_1-f_n)||\\
&\leq ||f_n -f_2||+||f_1-f_n|| (by triangle inequality)\\
& \to 0
\end{align*}
Therefore $||f_1-f_2|| =0 \Rightarrow f_1=f_2$
Am I correct on this part ( i have not use the fact $||T||_*=1$)

**Proof ii**
Any help on the second part? 
Thanks

Comment: I did use $T(f) = ||f||$ " Based on $T(f) =||f||$ we have $||f_n|| \to ||f_1||$"

Comment: As Bennibenben pointed out, there are 2 problems with your proof of part I.
First, $T(f_n)=\|f_n\|$ does not necessarily hold for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Second, the part where you show that $\|f_1 - f_2 \| \to 0$ is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By dual representation of the norm and the continuity of $| \, |$you have
$$\|f\|=\sup_{\|\varphi\|=1} |\varphi(f)|=\sup_{\|\varphi\|=1} lim_{n \to \infty} |\varphi(f_n)|\leq \liminf \sup_{\|\varphi\|=1}  |\varphi(f_n)|\leq\liminf \|f_n\|$$

Comment: I see you used this: $||\varphi||_* = \sup \{\varphi(f) | f \in X ||f||\leq 1\}$  Am i correct on the first part?

Comment: I don't think so. notice that for $f_1 $ and $f_2$ there exist two not necessarily same operators $T_1$ and $T_2$ such that $\|f_1\|=T_1(f_1)$ and $\|f_2\|=T_2(f_2)$. my approach would be to consider $T_0$ such that $T_0(f_1-f_2)=\|f_1-f_2\|$

Comment: I have to disagree: i don't think you need different operators, base on Royden weak convergent definition page 163, $f_n  \rightharpoonup f$ in X  $\Leftrightarrow T(f_n) \to T(f)$ for all $T \in X^*$ so i can choose like you said $T_0$ for both limits but it doesn't have to be unique

Comment: yes you only need $T_0$. I just wanted to point out that it is important to notice that if  you have $T(f)=\|f\|$ $T(f_n)=\|f_n\|$ does not necessarily hold for all $n\in \mathbb N$.